# Angular 2 - Can't bind to 'controlGroup' since it isn't a know property of the 'div' element

Tags: angular, typescript1.5

I'm trying to build a small app using Angular2.0.0-alpha.28 (with corresponding .d.ts) + TypeScript 1.5.0-beta and I got the following message:

> Can't bind to 'controlGroup' since it isn't a know property of the
>   'div' element and there are no matching directives with a
>   corresponding property

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Angular 2</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" />

<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>

<radar>Loading...</radar>
<script>System.import('radar-view');</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**radar-view.ts**

```
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, formDirectives, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
selector: 'radar',
appInjector: [FormBuilder]
})
@View({
template: '<div [control-group]="form"><input control="levels">    {{form.controls.levels.value}}</div>',
directives: [formDirectives]
})
export class RadarView {
form: ControlGroup;
builder: FormBuilder;

constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
    this.builder = builder;
    this.form = builder.group({
        levels: ["5"]
    });
}
}

bootstrap(RadarView);
```

**compiling**

```
tsc --watch --target es5 --module commonjs --emitDecoratorMetadata
```

Also when I try to use validators.required it looks like it's not found either:

```
this.form = builder.group({
    levels: ["5", Validators.required]
});
```

> Error:(21, 38) TS2339: Property 'required' does not exist on type
>   'typeof Validators'.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to schmck Validators.required is actually not part of the regular angular2.d.ts v.2.0.0-alpha.28.

For this issue the solution is to add the following to angular2.d.ts:

```
class Validators {
    static required: any;
}
```

Also from Pawel Kozlowski (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2779), 
`<div [control-group]="form"><input control="levels">`
must be replaced by 
`<div [ng-control-group]="form"><input ng-control="levels">`. 
This still doesn't work as I get now 
`No provider for ControlContainer! ($__0 -> ControlContainer)`.

Comment: I realize you'd probably have a solution by now, but for others stumbling in here through Google, the usual solution for your `ControlContainer` error is to ensure the element with `ngControlGroup` is placed within a `<form>` element.

Answer (score 3):

**FormBuilder** seems abandoned since Alpha.28. You should use **NgFormModel** instead like this(in *ES6*):

```
import {Component,View,bootstrap} from "angular2/angular2";
import {Control,ControlGroup,formDirectives} from "angular2/forms";

@Component({selector:"ez-app"})
@View({
    template : `
        <div [ng-form-model]="controls">
            <input type="text" ng-control="name">
            <input type="text" ng-control="age">
        </div>
        <!--following part will chanage as you input-->
        <pre>{{dump()}}</pre>
        `
})    
class EzComp{
    constructor(){
        this.controls = new ControlGroup({
            name :new Control("Jason"),
            age : new Control("45")
        });
    } 
    dump(){
        return JSON.stringify(this.controls.value,null,"\t");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you see that form builder has been abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your import statement location:

`import {FormBuilder, Validators, formDirectives, ControlGroup} from 'angular2/angular2';`

to `from 'angular2/forms'`;

Comment: `angular2/forms` doesn't seem to exist in angular2.d.ts (2.0.0-alpha.28). I also tried with some other versions and still doesn't work.

Comment: Line 2105 in [angular2.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular2/angular2.d.ts) exports 'angular2/forms'

Comment: Indeed angular2.d.ts contains ```angular2/forms```, thanks! Unfortunately my Typescript compiler still complains: ```error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'angular2/forms'.``` Any idea?

Comment: Try [this angular.d.ts](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/blob/master/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts) file, updated 11 hours ago.

Comment: Thanks but still the same error message. I tried to uninstall / reinstall typescript 1.5.0-beta on my mac using npm. Doesn't help either. Does the compilation work on your side?

Comment: I've used [this setup with webpack + typescript](https://github.com/angular-class/angular2-webpack-starter). Looking at the typings folder might help, it seems to be constructed of a few needed hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 is changing a lot from one release to another, the properties are constantly renamed, that's why you probably can't get it to work. The documentation isn't updated accordingly.

For a video tutorial of a working todo sample application with form validation please check out my screencast, it's open source.

https://youtu.be/267ClmzfzvI

https://github.com/ajtowf/ng2_overview/tree/ng2